# How to use 'useErrorHandler()' in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am looking at the `react-error-boundary` library from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary#useerrorhandlererror-error) but I do not understand how to use the `useErrorHandler(error?: Error)`prop.

So lets say I wrap my app with the error boundary - something like this

```
import {ErrorBoundary} from 'react-error-boundary';

<ErrorBoundary onError={myErrorHandler}>
  <App />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

How do I use 'useErrorHandler' to catch errors in the asynchronous code callbacks for example to propagate to `ErrorBoundary` so I can then use `myErrorHandler`?

Where is 'useErrorHandler' defined or imported?

I am trying to use this as a catch all error setup - sort of when you add throws excection to the main in java.

async code example:

```
  ...
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      axios({
        ...
      })
        .then((res) => {
          resolve(res);
          // <-- ?
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
```

Comment: From the docs you linked it seems `useErrorHandler` is to be used to handle errors that aren't handled by the react framework, i.e. the ones typically handled by an error boundary. There's even an example in the docs. I guess what may be confusing is the `handleError` callback is being passed *as* the Promise chain's then-able rejection handler. Looks like you can even directly pass error objects to `useErrorHandler`. Do you have an example of some asynchronous code of yours where you're wanting to use the error hook?

Comment: @DrewReese added an example

Comment: If I assume that is some utility function that returns a Promise, then in the function invoking it it can call `handleError` in a `.catch` of a promise chain, or the `catch` block of a try/catch. I actually meant for an example of your react component code that is calling some asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation doesn't make it clear about how to import the `useErrorHandler` function, but it's part of the API, so you can import in the same way that you import `ErrorBoundary`.

`import { useErrorHandler } from 'react-error-boundary';`

E.g.: (based on [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary#useerrorhandlererror-error))

```js
    import { useErrorHandler } from 'react-error-boundary';
    
    function Greeting() {
      const [greeting, setGreeting] = React.useState(null)
      const handleError = useErrorHandler()
     
      function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const name = event.target.elements.name.value
        fetchGreeting(name).then(
          newGreeting => setGreeting(newGreeting),
          handleError,
        )
      }
     
      return greeting ? (
        <div>{greeting}</div>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input id="name" />
          <button type="submit"}>
            get a greeting
          </button>
        </form>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Seems like useErrorHandler was taken out of 'react-error-boundary'